# python cut string in equivalent javascript substr

Tags: javascript, python

I have this piece of code in python, that cut a string using a constant value

```py
# CONST is a constant number
result = str[-CONST-4:-CONST]
```

I want convert the previous code in equivalent Javascript using `substr()` method or other similar methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `a_string[-N]` in python that is roughly analogous to `a_string[a_string.length-N]` in javascript, so `a_string[-CONST-4]` is the same as `a_string[a_string.length-CONST-4]`

if you wanted to exactly mimic it

```
let start_index = mystr.length - CONST - 4
let len =  (mystr.length - CONST) - start_index
let result = mystr.substr(start_index,len)
```

but you could probably just shorten it to

`let result = mystr.substr(mystr.length-CONST-4,4)`